# Adding an in-page search and display within a Mediawiki page

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-extensions, mediawiki-templates

I have been requested to add some functionality to a Mediawiki page. I am learning MW as fast as I can.  We have a MW page with a very large wikitable of bibliographic data.  The data is also kept in an external Excel file. It has been requested to add an input field and button so that visitors can search that bibliography and redisplay just the rows that contain a match for the search.  I've looked at a lot of extensions and have tried to work out how I could patch together this functionality (Maybe External Data and URLGetParameters but how to do the input field?)  I've thought about using an Iframe for the whole thing, and simply do it in PHP using the external spreadsheet but then the information in the IFrame is not visible to the MediaWiki search, yes? Perhaps Javascript/JQuery but I haven't worked out how to execute that on a MW page yet.  Does anyone know a proven path for doing this type of thing so I can possibly cut out some of the dead ends I am investigating?

Comment: It looks like you need *Semantic MediaWiki* to store the book references in internal objects and use *Special:Semantic search* to filter them.

Comment: There are plenty of ways to do this, some if which might or might not work for you depending on the details of the situation (e.g. exactly how large that table is). You could use a pure frontend solution for example, using one of the zillion table searching/filtering Javascript libraries.